# how download specific image files from a web site and convert those images to email addresses?

Tags: c#, image, email

there is a web site that converts all inside emails to images like below :

[image]

is there a way to get these email addresses?
mean is there a software can do this job or can i write a code for doing that?

Comment: If you have a legitimate purpose for doing this, (aka not spam), I suggest you post it here, before you go very far into the negative votes range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you ever think they are showing those email addresses as images for a reason? And perhaps that reason was so a program couldn't scrape the addresses, and proceed to spam them?

Anyway, what you are looking for is called [Optical Character Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) (OCR).

Here are several Stack Overflow questions that ask about OCR:

- [Any open source C# OCR library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744966/any-open-source-c-sharp-ocr-library)
- [Need C# OCR Library to Convert Image to Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410335/need-c-sharp-ocr-library-to-convert-image-to-text)
- [Any free OCR Library for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512271/any-free-ocr-library-for-c)

The general consensous is that [Tesseract for .NET](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/) is the way to go here, as it is open source.

But please, don't spam, or we will all have to hate you.